# mount.cifs: Any way to mount with kerberos using the machine credentials

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos, mount, cifs

When a Linux machine joins a domain, a computer account is created in Active Directory.

Can this account be used to mount a network share with cifs and Kerberos?

Comment: First, you'll need to setup Kerberos SSO using a keytab file.   Once that's in place, follow the scenario here which matches your use case:  https://centrify.force.com/support/Article/KB-18311-How-to-mount-a-CIFS-share-from-Linux-using-Kerberos/.

Comment: @T-Heron Are you sure it can work with a machine account only? When I run `klist` I see my user's ticket, not the machine's.

Comment: klist -li 0x3e7   --->  will give you a list of the system account’s tickets

Comment: @T-Heron I only see my user in the list (in the Principal name column).

Comment: That's because `klist -li` does a completely different thing in Windows; using `klist -li 0x3e7` on Linux is outright meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure *root* (uid 0) has a Kerberos ticket cache for the machine account – the tickets can be acquired using the system keytab, e.g. with `kinit -k`. However, to automatically maintain and renew them, you might need to run [kstart](https://www.eyrie.org/%7Eeagle/software/kstart/) as a system daemon. (It is not enough to just call kinit on startup, as valid tickets will be necessary whenever the connection is lost and re-established, e.g. if the SMB server gets rebooted.)

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/k5start -f /etc/krb5.keytab -U -k /tmp/krb5cc_0 -o root -b -K 60 -v -L
```

Oh, and make sure that the system actually *has* a Kerberos keytab for its machine account. (Use `klist -k` to check the keytab's contents.) SSSD/adcli joins will always have one at /etc/krb5.keytab, but joining using Samba might not generate one by default.

Once root has a ticket cache, you should be able to just mount SMB with `-o sec=krb5,multiuser`, and as root is performing the mount, its tickets will be used. This should work from /etc/fstab all the same, as long as you ensure that the 'kstart' service does its job earlier than the SMB mounts are attempted, e.g. by using the fstab option `x-systemd.requires=kstart.service`.

Comment: Note that, individual users still need to provide vaild kerberos to access the share.
If you want the users/scripts can run without providing tickets themselves, delegation and impersonate are required.